# What initialization should be made prior to calling InternetGetProxyInfo()?

Tags: c++, wininet

I configured internet explorer to use a local PAC file:
[image: ie proxy settings]

It works just fine. But when I try to call `InternetGetProxyInfo()`, it fails with `ERROR_CAN_NOT_COMPLETE`. What can be the problem?

```
#ifndef WINVER              // Allow use of features specific to Windows XP or later.
#define WINVER 0x0501       // Change this to the appropriate value to target other versions of Windows.
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT        // Allow use of features specific to Windows XP or later.                   
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501 // Change this to the appropriate value to target other versions of Windows.
#endif                      

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define URL "http://www.yandex.ru/"
#define HOST "www.yandex.ru"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char proxyBuffer[1024];
    char *str = proxyBuffer;
    DWORD nb = 1024;
    DWORD dw;
    BOOL b;
    pfnInternetGetProxyInfo pIGPI;                // Function-pointer instance

    /* code from MSDN: */    
    {
        HMODULE hModJS;                               // Handle for loading the DLL

        hModJS = LoadLibrary( TEXT("jsproxy.dll") );
        if (!hModJS)
        {
        _tprintf( TEXT("\nLoadLibrary failed to load jsproxy.dll with error: %d\n"),
        GetLastError( ) );
        return( FALSE );
        }

        pIGPI = (pfnInternetGetProxyInfo)
        GetProcAddress( hModJS, "InternetGetProxyInfo" );
        if (!pIGPI)         
        {
        _tprintf( TEXT("\nGetProcAddress failed to find InternetGetProxyInfo, error: %d\n"),
        GetLastError( ) );
        return( FALSE );
        }

        // The pIGPI function pointer can now be used to call InternetGetProxyInfo.
    }

    InternetInitializeAutoProxyDll(0); /* wininet.dll version of this function */
    SetLastError(0);
    b = pIGPI(URL,sizeof(URL),HOST,sizeof(HOST), &str, &nb);
    dw = GetLastError();

    SetLastError(0);
    b = pIGPI(URL,sizeof(URL)-1,HOST,sizeof(HOST)-1, &str, &nb);
    dw = GetLastError();

    return 0;
}
```

Please don't tell me to use other API, it's an educational, not practical question.

Comment: [Have you seen this?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931195/en-us)

Comment: @sftrabbit yes "for the first time". As you can see I call pIGPI() twice.

Comment: I found that `InternetInitializeAutoProxyDll()` in `wininet.dll` is just a stub.

Comment: But `wininet.dll` knows how to call `InternetInitializeAutoProxyDll()` in `jsproxy.dll` with the right arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

- easy: call `InternetOpenUrl()` with a dummy URL to let `wininet` initialize jsproxy:

  ```
  #define URL "https://yandex.ru:777"
  #define HOST "yandex.ru"
  HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen(_T("try-wininet"), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
  HINTERNET hUrl = InternetOpenUrl(hInternet, _T("http://0.0.0.0"), NULL, 0, 0, 20);
  InternetCloseHandle(hUrl);
  InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
  InternetGetProxyInfo(URL,sizeof(URL)-1,HOST,sizeof(HOST)-1, &str, &nb);
  GlobalFree(str);
  ```
- hard: call `InternetInitializeAutoProxyDll()` in jsproxy. But to prepare the arguments, you have to do everything yourself: read the settings from the registry, parse them, detect and download the PAC file and provide an implementation of `AutoProxyHelperVtbl` that contains such functions as `GetIPAddress()`, `IsInNet()`, etc.

`InternetGetProxyInfo()` fails when there's no PAC script configured, although some proxy server is set in the bottom of the dialog. In this case you should call `InternetQueryOption(NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY,...)`